# rosdep fails to find libeigen3-dev on debian:squeeze

Tags: ros, eigen, rosdep, debian, eigen3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Trying to build the 'robot' variant under debian:squeeze, having some trouble with this libeigen3-dev.

libeigen3-dev is listed for jessie, sid, and wheezy, but not for squeeze. Which makes sense as the package is not officially supported for squeeze. There is a supported. libeigen2-dev.

I was able to install from a downloaded .deb package (eg wget from ftp.us.debian.org, with libeigen3-dev_3.1.0-1_i386.deb or _armel.deb or whatever), this seems to have installed fine but i haven't got as far as testing the build since there are still other missing/problematic dependencies. But maybe someone will have an answer before i go much further with the others.

many thanks
dave

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130726/rosdep-fails-to-find-libeigen3-dev-on-debian:squeeze/) by [dave.peacock](https://answers.ros.org/users/12111/dave.peacock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-18**:
So what exactly is the question?

**Comment by [dave.peacock](https://answers.ros.org/users/12111/dave.peacock/) on 2014-02-18**:
Ha, good question. I guess I was asking "Is installing libeigen3-dev manually the right thing to do on debian:squeeze", ahendrix's answer is sufficient for me, and hopefully this helps others running into the same or similar problems, but maybe squeeze is too old for a lot of hydro stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you're heading in the right direction by finding a libeigen3-dev to use. I suspect most of the code that uses eigen won't be backwards-compatible to older versions of eigen.

It sounds like you can manually tell rosdep that libeigen3 is installed according to https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/15

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dave.peacock](https://answers.ros.org/users/12111/dave.peacock/) on 2014-02-18**:
Thanks, looks like the manual install worked, but link will prove useful for some other deps. But maybe robot variant is too much to ask of squeeze, geometry stack causing more grief. REP-131 suggests variants were getting phased out as of groovy, maybe should be using metapackages instead.